# Setting Autolayout programatically in swift not working

Tags: swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have added one sampleuiview(200,200) in my storyBoardViewController and coonected its outlet with viewcontroller.

Now i want to add some constraints suppose (Top - 200,Leading-100 , Trailing -100)  and some widhth , height  and Centre Position

I wrote a code as:

```
boxView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: boxView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 60)
self.view.addConstraint(leading)

let widthC = NSLayoutConstraint(item: boxView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 60)
self.view.addConstraint(widthC)

let heightC = NSLayoutConstraint(item: boxView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)
self.view.addConstraint(heightC)

let centerX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: boxView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 150)
self.view.addConstraint(centerX)

let centerY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: boxView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
self.view.addConstraint(centerY)
```

But its not working. Is there any issue?

P.S boxView is my subview added in xib file

Comment: Did you call [controller.view setNeedsDisplay]?

Comment: Where in what method is this code called?

Comment: i have added in viewWill Appear 
[where do i need to setneedsdisplay?]

Comment: "But its not working" What does _that_ mean?

Comment: means what ever constant value i set , the box view remains at one static position. its position is not getting changed

Answer (score 0):

`self.view` is the subview of the viewcontroller and self.view cannot have any constraints. `boxView` can have constraints so that it's position and size can be relative to `self.view` which is its superview.

It's fine to add constraints in `viewWillAppear` and `setNeedsDisplay` is not needed.

Are you trying to position `boxView` inside the view controller?

Comment: i have added boxView in Storyboard xib file.(using drag -drop) . and connected its outlet connection, and then programatically i want to set its constraints , i just want to see how to set the autolayout in that way, so i can playaround with it with more animations